# Story regarding suspended animation and human-shaped felines

Tags: story-identification

A scientist is struck by lightning and wakes up several millennia into the future.

One of his first encounters is with a seemingly human female that has many feline characteristics - including a tail and long ears with Siamese cat marking.

There are also vegetable-based engines and an extremely large semi-intelligent forest.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you provide any further details about this? Was it a novel? A film? An animated series? When did you watch/read it? Anything at all that you can remember will potentially help us narrow it down to the right thing.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a story-id question; feel free to remove the tag if I'm wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Jim, could you please go through [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if there are any extra details you could add to this question?

Comment: Whatever it is, it totally ripped off Red Dwarf.

Answer (score 4):

Found it - 'The Stone God Awakens' (1973), by Philip José Farmer

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1526312.The_Stone_God_Awakens):

> A 20th century scientist is rendered frozen at the molecular level, and then reanimated millennia later by a freak accident to a strange world populated by sentient, anthropomorphic animals, who take his awakening to be the fulfillment of prophecy. He accepts the mantle of godhood and sets about discovering this brave new world, hoping to find clues to the past while finding his place as the last human... or is he? To find the answers he must lead his tribe of feline worshippers to the heart of a rival god- a great tree spanning half a continent.

Comment: Nice! You will be able to accept your answer in the next 48 hours by clicking the check mark on the left. I hope you stick around!